# One and Two Byte Wide

Tags: digital-logic, memory

Ok can someone explain to me what is considered One Byte Wide or Two Byte Wide? I couldn't find much on it. From what I know 8 bits = 1 byte? So lets say there's 16 bits and it needs to be 2 byte wide does that mean put it into 2 8 bits?

If this is confusing the specific question is 128K memory in 1 byte and 2 byte wide. So would 2 byte wide mean 2 64k? I'm confused and trying to grasp this concept so bear with me.

Answer (score 3):

2 bytes is 16 bits, plain and simple. "k" is not a unit of memory. "kb" is, as is "kB". The number of bits in a memory module doesn't change regardless of whether it is 8 bits or 16 bits wide, only how data is written to or read from it, i.e. 8 or 16 bits at a time.

Comment: Ok so in computer architecture this part I'm reading it shows a `Logical View` of a `1K x 1` memory and it requires a `10-bit address bus` i.e. a0 to a9. If this was a `128K` memory instead then does that mean it requires a `17-bit address bus`? Since 2^17 = 131,072. So it's a0 to a16?

Comment: Is is a 128k x 1b memory?

Comment: It just asks 128k is the 1b = 1 byte? It asks both for 1 byte and the 2 byte wide

Comment: "b" is bits, "B" is bytes.

Comment: Ok the question just asks for 128K Logical View in 1 byte wide and 2 byte.

Comment: 128k *what*? If there's no unit then the question is ambiguous.

Comment: You're right, I'm always confused by the questions that is asked. It just says, `Draw a Logical View of a 128K memory: 1 Byte Wide and 2 Byte Wide` Can we just assume its 128k x 1?

Comment: Aaaaand that question is horrible. "Here's a picture of a rectangle with '128K' written in it with a bidirectional arrow for the data pins and unidirectional arrows for the address pins and various chip selects. Enjoy your logical view."

Comment: You have no idea how confusing most of the question are. Well I guess you do now but is there a better way to BS this? I would so write that but I still would like points for this, lol

Comment: As a last ditch effort I'd assume it was 128kb, draw it out like that, and chew out your teacher if you don't get marks for it.

Comment: Ok, i'll do that. What exactly is meant by 2 byte wide?

Comment: I suppose my answer never *directly* answered it, but it means that data is transferred 16 bits at a time.

Comment: Ok thanks, so that cleared things up. So 1 byte = 8 bits at a time. So it'll require more data regions to transfer 1 byte wide than 2 byte wide.

Comment: An 8-bit memory has more locations/addresses than a 16-bit memory of the same size.